# Блок выходит за границы тега body

Tags: html, css

Только начал верстку изучать и сразу затык))

```
html, body {
    font-family: Arial;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border: 3px solid black;
}

.block {
    height: 100%;
    border: 3px solid red;
}
```

Я предполагал, что div с классом block будет внутри body, но он внизу выходит за границы, как будто его просто переместили вниз целиком. Почему такое поведение?

Comment: Добавь `box-sizing: border-box;` всем элементом, и почитай про это свойство и будет ясно...

Comment: сделал, почитал, не поменялось. Все отступы на 0. Блок внутри боди. Почему он сдвинут относительно боди и выходит за пределы? Получается вниз и чуть вправо.

Comment: методом исключения остается проблема в теге div. Видимо, какие-то у него по умолчанию настройки

Comment: @Дмитрий скачай normalize.css или задай в стилях * {margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box;} div,img {display: block;} img {max-width: 100%; height: auto;} для начала. У вас в body по умолчанию браузером задаётся margin. Он также задаётся и во многих других тегах по умолчанию. Поэтому их надо перебивать своими стилями перед тем как начать верстать иначе будете постоянно искать, что же браузер самовольно вставил в стили.

Answer (score 2):

Всё правильно Вам в комментариях указали. Осталось только попробовать:

```css
html, body {
    font-family: Arial;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border: 3px solid black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.block {
    height: 100%;
    border: 3px solid red;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
```

Comment: всем спасибо, кто ответил))